# MySQL JOIN two tables on closest matching value

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following situation:

```
tableA
+-------+-------+
| id    | Value |
+-------+-------+
| 1     | 1000  |
| 2     | 20    |
| 3     | 62    |
| 4     | 0     |
+-------+-------+

tableB
+-------+--------+
| Value | Lookup |
+-------+--------+
|    10 | a      |
|    20 | b      |
|    30 | b      |
|    40 | g      |
|    50 | h      |
|    60 | f      |
|    70 | a      |
|    80 | a      |
|    90 | v      |
|   100 | b      |
+-------+--------+
```

And I need to return the lookup in table B that most closely matches the value field in table A. For example.

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| id    | Value | Lookup |
+-------+-------+--------+
| 1     | 1000  | b      |
| 2     | 20    | b      |
| 3     | 62    | f      |
| 4     | 0     | a      |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: If you're going to be here a while, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an option using joins:

```
SELECT
    a.Id, a.Value, b.Lookup
FROM tableA a
CROSS JOIN tableB b
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.Id, MIN(ABS(a.Value - b.Value)) AS min_abs_value
    FROM tableA a
    CROSS JOIN tableB b
    GROUP BY a.Id
) t
    ON a.Id = t.Id AND
       ABS(a.Value - b.Value) = t.min_abs_value;
```

[image]

### Demo

While this query *does* join to a subquery, the subquery is not correlated.

Comment: perfect exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Value, 
       (SELECT b.Lookup
       FROM TableB AS b
       ORDER BY ABS(a.Value - b.Value) LIMIT 1)
FROM TableA AS a
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f359a3/1)

Comment: great thanks works perfectly. But do you know how I can do this without using sub queries? Reason being is the data set that this lookup will be used on will be in excess of 100,000 rows and I would like to maximize performance.

Comment: @Josh for each record in `TableA` you need to do a `CROSS JOIN` with all records from `TableB` in order to calculate the `Value` difference. This is due to the design of your tables. So I don't think it is possible to solve this without a subquery.

Comment: @Josh ...but it doesn't need to be correlated